# running background thread in android throughout the application

Tags: android

hi i am new to android. can anybody help me to solve this. 
i want to run a background thread which will request to the server response in some time gaps. this threads have to be run in background through out the application.  if any one know how do this in android please let me know.i hope you understood my problem .thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

basically you are looking for services
see [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html)

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for a [service.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html)